# Console.log isn't working with express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, server, console.log

```
var app=require('express')();
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var players=[];
var io=require('socket.io')(http);

const port=8000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+ '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection',(socket) => {
    console.log(socket,'connected!');

    socket.on('disconnect',() => {
        console.log(socket,'disconnected!');
    });

});

http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

I'm trying to make a server to learn express with socket and node...But when i run this program console.log() doesn't work and in the cmd doesn't appear nothing.

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using in `index.html` to set up the `socket.io` client?

Comment: Oh man right!Now i understand why is not working...I forgot to declare a thing in the index...Thank you so much!

Comment: Haha you're welcome ;D

Comment: @ImFireblade - Can you please update here what changes you have done in the index?